# Validation of virtual attributes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running Ruby (1.9.3) on Rails (3.2.0) and having a problem with the validation of virtual attributes.

I have a `Flight` model that represents a flight which, among others, has an attributes that represents the airport of departure and arrival.

Because the `select` for selecting an airport is potentially huge, I opted to go for an autocomplete solution, which is working perfectly fine. I am using a `before_validation` callback to properly populate the actual ID of the airport:

```
before_validation do
  self.departure_airport = Airport.find_by_long_name(departure_airport_name)
  self.arrival_airport = Airport.find_by_long_name(arrival_airport_name)
end
```

The problem is, however, that when the user enters the name of an airport that does not exist in the database, the commit fails because the ID of either airport is `nil`. Great. What's not great, however, is that this validation failure is not reflected on the form because technically, it's the input for another field:

```
validates :departure_airport, :arrival_airport presence: true

attr_accessor :departure_airport_name, :arrival_airport_name

<%= f.input :departure_airport_name %>
<%= f.input :arrival_airport_name %>
```

Is this even the way to properly go about, transforming the name of the airport into an ID in the `before_validation` callback? And if so, how can I get the validation errors to show up on the virtual name attribute of the airport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are going the right way with the `before_validation` callback.

You can validate virtual attributes like every normal attribute. So all you need is just some validation in the model. Try this:

```
validates :departure_airport, presence: true
validates :arrival_airport, presence: true
```

this should add an error to the objects errors and the error should be displayed in your form...

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! I already have validations on the `departure_airport` and `arrival_airport`. The problem is that these are not the fields that `input`'s on the form represent. I can't simply validate presence because when someone types text in them, the field is present, but the actual `Airport` object is going to be missing.

Comment: Thats why you register the `before_validation` callback. When the user enters gibberish, it wont find the airport and the validation will fail. An error will be added and displayed to the user. Maybe you should consider adding a custom error massage.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I did not get it. Maybe you need your own validation method. You can add errors to the object with `self.errors.add( :fieldname, "message")`. If you now use the `departure_airport_name` as fieldname and add a message, it will get displayed in the `departure_airport_name` field.