# Rails ActiveRecord non db attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got an ActiveRecord model, `Instance`, which is based in the database, but has some non-database attributes.

One example is 'resolution'.

I need to be able to set/get the resolution, but this attribute needs custom non-db setters/getters. Where do I put these & how do I structure my model?

I also need to be able to validate resolutions as they are set via regex. Can I use `validates_format_of` or do I need to code a custom Validator?

Comment: How do you "structure" your model? Add the methods.

Comment: You can validate virtual attributes like every normal attribute -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9749292/429758

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me; I've got `validates_format_of :resolution, with: /\d+x+\d+/` outside the writer method, but it seems to be being ignored. Do I need to write something specific?

Comment: validates_format_of() is an ActiveRecord validation, so if you are doing a database transaction it is possible to piggyback a validation of a non-database field, like your resolution. But if you are not, which it seems is the case from your code, then you will need to write your own custom validator. If you want, if you think it's useful for someone else later who has this problem,  make this an answer, if not I'll just leave it as a comment. Piggybacking ex: validates_format_of :resolution, :with => /\d+x+\d+/, :on => :create

Answer (score 3):

If you need standard reader/writer methods, you can use `attr_accessor`:

```
class Instance
  attr_accessor :resolution
end
```

You can also write the reader and writer method by yourself:

```
class Instance
  def resolution
    @resolution
  end

  def resolution=(value)
    @resolution = value
    validate! # this will raise RecordInvalid if the validation fails
  end
end
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! I've got `validates_format_of :resolution, with: /\d+x+\d+/` outside the writer method, but it seems to be being ignored. Do I need to write something specific?

Comment: Can you show the code, where the record is created and validated?

Comment: I did it exactly the way you wrote it; I just called from console `Instance.last.resolution = 'asdf'`. Unfortunately, instead of throwing an error, it continued to run the writer.

Comment: Well, the validation will happen only as soon as you try to save the record. It should not throw an error while assigning the attribute

Comment: What's the best approach to validate in this case then?

Comment: I removed that comment to double check something. Still looking. Will post momentarily.

Comment: well, if you need to raise an error right on the assignment, you call the `validate!` method right after assigning the attribute

Comment: Are you doing a validation immediately prior to saving the record?

Comment: Not exactly - it seems to be rejecting everything now - I'm trying `Instance.last.resolution = '640x480'` with the rule specified in my first comment

Comment: There is no 'saving of record' here. As this is not a database transaction, I don't call update. The resolution is sent to the node via SSH, so I've got an algo in the resolution method that does that.

Comment: Can you try the validation with this regex? `\A\d+x{1}\d+\z`

Comment: Yes, same problem, ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Resolution is invalid